# Does the NHibernate session object use a lot of server RAM?

Tags: nhibernate, session

Does the [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) session object use a lot of server RAM?

It depends on website traffic, but does the session object get very big in terms of memory usage?

Comment: Can someone who can edit change the 'allot' to 'a lot' in the title and first sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The ISession object is a very lightweight object, ISessionFactory not.

Answer (score 0):

It can - it depends on how you're using it. The session is your unit of work, so typically only exists for a short period of time. It acts as your first level of cache, storing the entities that it has dealt with throughout its lifetime.

If you're keeping your sessions alive for a long time, they will potentially become more and more bogged down with cached entities. In certain scenarios, you can use `ISession.Evict` to remove an entity from the session if there's no reason for it to be kept in there.